# firebase clearAllNotifications() not working in ionic 3

Tags: firebase, push-notification, ionic3

I need to remove old notification form status bar in ionic 3.

I have used firebase plugin( **"@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.20.0"** and **"cordova-plugin-firebase": "2.0.5"**). Here is **app.component.ts** file

```
  import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';

  constructor(private platform: Platform,
      statusBar: StatusBar,
      splashScreen: SplashScreen,
      public firebase: Firebase) {

        platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.firebase.clearAllNotifications().then(clearData => {
                console.log('removed all notification');
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('error in removing notification');
            });
        });
    }
```

and gives error something like

```
ERROR: Unhandled Promise rejection: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.fcm.clearAllNotifications().then') ; Zone: <root> ; Task: setTimeout ; Value: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.fcm.clearAllNotifications().then')
```

how can I achieve this functionality, can anyone please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Write a native interface and put handler.delay ay be ur ui thread is queued with too much items

Comment: can you please provide the android logcat when u r opening the app ?

Answer (score 1):

```
@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.20.0"
```

has no method available called `clearAllNotifications()` you have to download the latest version or need to add manually [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/src/%40ionic-native/plugins/firebase/index.ts#L346)